# Compiling Python 3.1.1 32-bit

Tags: python

We're using this configure script with an option we spotted in the configure help menu:

```
./configure --with-universal-archs=32-bit --prefix="$HOME/python"
make
make install
```

But when all the dust is settled and we check out what it gives us:

```
✔python-3.1.1⤿ file ~/python/bin/python3
python/bin/python3: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

How do we compile it so we're given a 32-bit python? We're looking to use the uno module provided by OpenOffice, which requires 32-bit python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to build your own.  Use the [Python 3.1.1 OS X installer from python.org](http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.1.1/).  It's 32-bit only and will work just fine on OS X 10.4 through 10.6.  If you need to install any packages with C extension modules on 10.6, you'll need to install the optional 10.4 SDK from the the Snow Leopard Xcode mpkg and you'll need to tell Distutils to use GCC 4.0:

```
$ export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.0
```

Comment: Whilst I have accepted this answer, this only answers about compiling Python 32-bit and not the other half of the question which involves using OpenOffice's uno python module which is not compatible with 3.1.1. We press on.

Comment: I'm not familiar with uno but, in general, many 3rd-party modules have not yet been tested with nor modified to work with Python 3, which is why both Python 2 and Python 3 are being developed and maintained in parallel and will be for some time in the future.  Unless you have a pressing need for features in Python 3, many people would recommend sticking with Python 2 for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try `CFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32` although I don't have the requisite hardware to test that it works.

I'm not familiar with the `--with-universal-archs` option -- must be specific to OS X?